# What are Torch Scripts in PyTorch?

Tags: pytorch, jit

I've just found that PyTorch docs expose something that is called [Torch Scripts](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/jit.html?highlight=model%20features). However, I do not know:

- When they should be used?
- How they should be used?
- What are their benefits?

Comment: I also did a short tutorial with a practical scenario using torch scripts if you are interested: http://blog.christianperone.com/2018/10/pytorch-1-0-tracing-jit-and-libtorch-c-api-to-integrate-pytorch-into-nodejs/

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Torch Script is one of two modes of using the PyTorch [just in time compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation), the other being [tracing](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/jit.html#torch.jit.trace). The benefits are explained in the linked documentation:

> Torch Script is a way to create serializable and optimizable models from PyTorch code. Any code written in Torch Script can be saved from your Python process and loaded in a process where there is no Python dependency.

The above quote is actually true both of scripting and tracing. So

1. You gain the ability to serialize your models and later run them outside of Python, via LibTorch, a C++ native module. This allows you to embed your DL models in various production environments like mobile or IoT. There is an official guide on exporting models to C++ [here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/advanced/cpp_export.html).
2. PyTorch can *compile* your jit-able modules rather than running them as an interpreter, allowing for various optimizations and improving performance, both during training and inference. This is equally helpful for development and production.

Regarding Torch Script specifically, in comparison to tracing, it is a subset of Python, specified in detail [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/jit_language_reference.html#language-reference), which, when adhered to, can be compiled by PyTorch. It is more laborious to write Torch Script modules instead of tracing regular `nn.Module` subclasses, but it allows for some extra features over tracing, most notably flow control like `if` statements or `for` loops. Tracing treats such flow control as "constant" - in other words, if you have an `if model.training` clause in your module and trace it with `training=True`, it will always behave this way, even if you change the `training` variable to `False` later on.

To answer your first question, you *need* to use `jit` if you want to deploy your models outside Python and otherwise you *should* use `jit` if you want to gain some execution performance at the price of extra development effort (as not every model can be straightforwardly made compliant with `jit`). In particular, you should use Torch Script if your code cannot be `jit`ed with tracing alone because it relies on some features such as `if` statements. For maximum ergonomy, you probably want to [mix the two](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/jit.html#mixing-tracing-and-scripting) on a case-by-case basis.

Finally, for *how* they should be used, please refer to all the documentation and tutorial links.

Comment: @Jatentaki  So, for-loop shall also use Torch Script instead of trace mode, right? b/c trace mode can not handle the control-flow?

Comment: @coder yes, unless the loop always executes the same operations the same amount of times, then it is fine to use tracing. For example if you were reimplementing `nn.Sequential` as `for module in self: x = module(x)`, it is fine to use tracing as the modules contained in `self` do not change between executions. If the loop depended on `x` then you have to use script.